# Bootstrap 3.3.7 - carousel not showing content of div marked with class - 'item'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have created a simple page which contain only one bootstrap carousel.

I have included following script files

- bootstrap.css
- jquery-1.11.1.min.js
- bootstrap.js

**Problem**: I can see only image sliding.  Other content of div with the class 'item' is not appearing on the slides.  I want to include other stuff over the image to add more description.  Just like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) link.

But I cant see other content, can see only images sliding.  Am i missing any style sheet or js file?

```html
 <body>
      <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item">
                            <img class="first-slide" src="" alt="First slide">
                            <div class="container">
                                <-- I cant see below divs !-->
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item active">
                            <img class="second-slide" src="" alt="Second slide"> 
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                            img class="third-slide" src="" alt="Third slide"> 
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span>Letf</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
     </body>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr_shelar/hf3wegse/) link.

Comment: You have to set `min-height` for `.container` yourself  https://jsfiddle.net/hf3wegse/3/

Comment: @Wolff , Perfect.  It's working fine.  Thanks a lot....

Answer (score -2):

check the third section of your code

\
"img class="third-slide" src="" alt="Third slide">"

you missed to insert the "<" ... http://prntscr.com/hjaonu

Comment: hi @felix manzanas, thanks for picking that.  I have updated jsfiddle but still I am having same issue.

Comment: i test in my locahost promise its working, please check this >> http://prntscr.com/hjauz4, and then your "active" must placed in the first section please check this also >> http://prntscr.com/hjaw7y

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated it in to jsfiddle.  But still have same issue. Wolff has identified the issue and after adding that style its working fine.   https://jsfiddle.net/hr_shelar/hf3wegse/16/